# Whats a MySprite?

Tags: python, pygame

I understand that this could a be a possible repeat of another question, but I'm really confused. I'm reading the book "More Python Programming For The Absolute Beginner". In it there's a chapter for creating an RPG. The book teaches you by showing the part of the code and then explains to you why you use it and what it is. It does that for the whole code. I got to it and the book told me to enter this:

```
tiles = list()
for y in range(0,45):
    for x in range(0,80):
        tiles.append(8)
text = MySprite()
text.load("ascii8*12.png", 8, 12, 32)
```

I followed it exactly but it says that MySprite is not defined. I could not figure out why it wasn't defined, so I asked the community why my MySprite wasn't defined. The community replied asking me what my MySprite was. I really don't understand that. So what I'm asking is what is a MySprite. The book doesn't explain it. I've been working at this for awhile and can't seem to figure it out. Also I don't understand how to define it. But more importantly I want to know what a MySprite is. Sorry for the lengthy question and story.
Thanks

Comment: it's undoubtedly an object YOU have to define yourself, that implements sprite-like behavior

Comment: I wouldn't trust a book with a logically inconsistent title like _"More Python Programming For The Absolute Beginner"_. Presumably anyone doing _more_ is no longer an absolute beginner.

Comment: Look at [page 116](http://books.google.com/books?id=2ZQLAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PT135#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the book.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `MySprite` looks like a class, and the line `text = MySprite()` creates an instance of that class and assigns it to the `text` variable. Somewhere in your book there should be a definition for that class with an instance method called load. It should look something like:

```
class MySprite:
  # Possibly some other code here
  def load(self, filename, width, height, another_argument):
    # Loading code here
```